# iOs 10 - SWIFT 3 - Notification push

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I have a little problem with notification push and iOs 10 (with Swift 3)..

I followed this tutorial : https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-push-notifications-for-ios-10/
With **Pusher**, it's ok, works fine..
I receive the notification on my phone.

But I would like to send notifications from my web server..
I generate my .pem file (http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/)

My php code :

```
$apnsServer = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
$privateKeyPassword = 'mykey';
$message = "My message here !";
$deviceToken ='MYTOKENHERE';

$pushCertAndKeyPemFile = 'pushcert.pem';
$stream = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($stream,'ssl','passphrase',$privateKeyPassword);
stream_context_set_option($stream,'ssl','local_cert',$pushCertAndKeyPemFile);
$connectionTimeout = 30;
$connectionType = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT;
$connection = stream_socket_client($apnsServer, $errorNumber, $errorString, $connectionTimeout,$connectionType,$stream);

if (!$connection){
    echo "Failed to connect to the APNS server. Error = $errorString <br/>";
    exit;
}
else{
    echo "Successfully connected to the APNS. Processing...</br>";
}
$messageBody['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($messageBody);
$notification = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$wroteSuccessfully = fwrite($connection, $notification, strlen($notification));

if (!$wroteSuccessfully){
    echo "Could not send the message<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Successfully sent the message<br/>";
}
```

Result : 
**Successfully connected to the APNS. Processing...**
**Successfully sent the message** 
But I never receive notification on my phone

Why ?
How to send a notification push with php ?

Thanks for your help :)

**[EDIT]
Ok, i found a solution..
Just add at the end:**

```
fclose($connection);
```

Comment: You know that the device token is different for develop and release? Did u used the correct device token?

Comment: LoVo is correct the device id might have changed. Also, you have to make sure you are using production certificate  for PEM file

Comment: a .pem file is necessarily a production certificate ?
I built a development certificate and I converted to .pem
This is not the right way ?

Comment: Nobody has this problem? :/